# How to export MapPoint territories in lat/long boundries

Tags: dictionary, latitude-longitude, tableau-api, mappoint

I built out territories in MapPoint based on zip code grouping. Is there a way to export the long/lat of the territory boundaries? I know MapPoint knows the coordinates, but I can't find a way to export them.

[image]

If this capability is not available in MapPoint, is there another way/tool to get the boundary coordinates? I know of [DrawingTool for Tableau](http://drawingtool.powertoolsfortableau.com/), but that is manual drawing and there is no way to save and edit the map later.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Tableau the Latitudes,Longitudes are auto generated for a geo dimension.
If you want to export the details you can follow below steps.

- 1: Right click on the view
  2: Click on view data
  3: Click on export all
  4: save the exported file.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about the export of generated LAT/LONG. However, it does not export the boundaries of a colored territory, but each zip code .

Answer (score 0):

No MapPoint does not expose the boundary coordinates of any of the geographies (eg. zipcodes) in its database.

Territory export is also limited, as you've probably found. The API is even worse - you can't even query the individual component geographies (eg. which zipcodes make up each territory).

Might be overkill for you (being a full GIS), but Caliper's Maptitude 2016 has new territory functionality that is reminiscent of MapPoint's territories, but fixes the various problems that MapPoint had. It can also import territories from MapPoint PTM files.

Comment: So far its looking as if I have to hand draw each territory in Drawing Tool for Tableau...

Comment: I guess it depends how much your time is worth and how long it will take to redraw them! :-)

Comment: I have been delaying the task in hopes for a last minute solution. I heard Tableau's future releases will further support the polygon mapping feature. Here is to living on a prayer.